raspberry pi pico W software watchdog reset
I've built a system using Raspberry Pi Pico W (rp2040)  for recording the soil nutrient data using an NPK soil sensor and the data collected by the sensor is sent over to Thingsboard cloud using Quectel EG25g cellular module, the problem which I am facing is my device is getting stuck in GSM loop section the GSM module fails to turn off sometimes which bricks the device. It becomes unresponsive and for that issue, I have set a software watchdog timer. Still, it failed to reset my device when it was in the hung state;  however, when I was testing it by making the device fall in infinite  loop manually, the software watchdog worked very well but didn't work when the device was actually stuck in GSM mode. My device is placed in a very remote location which is a 2-hour drive from my city and I cannot go there every time just to reset the device manually.

I would be tempted to use a second Pico to control the power to the cellular module (and maybe even to the main Pico). It could monitor activity, and if there was a problem it could reboot the system. Also, depending on how frequently you needed to take measurements, you could even put in a physical power timer set to reboot your system at regular intervals (once a day or whatever).

Welcome. "the problem which I am facing is my device is getting stuck in GSM loop section the GSM module fails to turn off sometimes which bricks the device" -> Perhaps that is what you should be trying to solve then, since the software watchdog doesn't work, qv. the XY problem.

Did you check every item separately?
